# Pillow en contenedor de Docker

Tags: django, docker, pillow

Tengo entre manos un proyecto de Django y necesitaba un modelo con un campo ImageField, por lo que me requiere instalar la librería de Pillow y todo lanzado en un contenedor de docker.

El error que tengo es el siguiente:

Ya he modificado la imagen para instalar las dependencias de la librería Pillow, he modificado el requirements.txt para que instale Pillow y después de hacer el build de la imagen si ejecute dentro del contenedor
`pip freeze`

Me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Django @ file:///wheels/Django-2.2.17-py3-none-any.whl
djangorestframework @ file:///wheels/djangorestframework-3.12.2-py3-none-any.whl
gunicorn @ file:///wheels/gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Pillow @ file:///wheels/Pillow-8.0.1-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
psycopg2-binary @ file:///wheels/psycopg2_binary-2.8.6-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
PyJWT @ file:///wheels/PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
pytz @ file:///wheels/pytz-2020.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
sqlparse @ file:///wheels/sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

El problema viene cuando le digo al contenedor que haga el makemigrations, que me saca un error por pantalla y me dice que Pillow no está instalado.

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
authentication.Profile.avatar: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "pip install Pillow".
```

He estado buscando ya bastante información y no encuentro nada para solucionar este problema, ya he probado a rebuildear el contenedor, desisntalar y volver a instalar la librería y nada.

Os adjunto el Dockerfile principal, por si alguien viese algo fuera de lo normal.

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/Project

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    gcc jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg

# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install flake8
COPY . .
RUN flake8 --ignore=E501,F401 .

# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/Project/wheels -r requirements.txt

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/wac

# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S wac && adduser -S wac -G wac

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/wac
ENV APP_HOME=/home/wac/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/Project/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/Project/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh $APP_HOME

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R wac:wac $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER wac

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/wac/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo "le dices" al contenedor que haga la migración? ¿Qué comando usas?

Comment: ```sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec web python manage.py makemigrations```

Esta todo en un docker-compose, así que una vez desplegado procedo a ejecutar los comandos de makemigrations, migrate y dejarlo todo listo